# How to prevent users uploading images from their system?

Tags: 7, media

I have some image fields on my site.

My requirement is that the user should not be able to upload an image. Instead there will be a directory where I will place some images. And the user can only select an image from those images through image field.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are three major projects for handling media libraries in Drupal 7:

- [**IMCE**](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce)
- [**Media**](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)
- [**Scald**](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald)

The most basic solution is **IMCE**. It is simply a file browser for files on your server. I.e. image files are just files on your server and Drupal isn't really aware of them and their meta-data.

The **Media** module uses in its ver. 2.0 [**File Entity**](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module to manage media files, making it well aligned with the Drupal framework. It is a tried and tested solution for those who want something more sophisticated than **IMCE**.

**Scald** is a relatively new entry for media management. It comes with a very powerful media library sub-module and integrates seamlessly with the CKeditor WYSYWYG editor through drag and drop.  It has a bit steeper learning curve than the two others, but is IMHO well worth the effort.

Whether users are allowed to upload files (as opposed to pulling them from a library) are for all three projects handled by permissions settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require these two modules [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) and [IMCE filefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_filefield). Through this you can browse from exisiting directory and set images.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at FileField Sources. With this module you can control which sources are allowed per field.

Comment: May you provide a link to that project page?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that solves such cases specifically.
(Offer a few images for avatar selection, to the user.)

It also offers to disable 'upload' of user pictures.

https://www.drupal.org/project/avatar_selection

[image: https://www.drupal.org/files/images/avatar_selection_edit_account_screenshot.PNG]